# box2d difference between angles of two bodies

Tags: math, vector, geometry, box2d

Working with box2d and cocos2d, I've calculated two vectors:

- one is the vector pointing in the direction the car is travelling. (center of the vehicle to it's north point).
- two is the vector pointing in the direction of the target. (center to the vehicle to the target center.)

I need to rotate the vehicle to also point in the direction of the target. This is done by setting the vehicle's steering either 90 degrees to turn right or -90 to turn left.

At the moment i'm querying the box2d body of the vehicle for its angle, then calculating the angle of the target direction vector using:

```
if(vector.y == 0){ vector.y = 0.000001f; }
float baseRadians = atan(vector.x/vector.y);
if(vector.y < 0){ baseRadians += PI_CONSTANT; } //Adjust for -Y
return -1 * baseRadians;
```

The following is crude and where I need help...!

I then compare the angle of the vehicle against the angle returned from the direction vector and set the steering as follows:

```
if(vehicleAngle < targetAngle)
        {
            steeringInput = -90.0;    
        }
        else if(vehicleAngle > targetAngle)
        {
            steeringInput = 90.0;    
        }
        else
        {
            steeringInput = 0.0;     
        }
```

The problem is two fold:

- The target angle jumps from -4.71 to 1.57 radians, causing the vehicle to switch to the wrong direction
- The vehicle angle is continous and keeps increasing rather than staying within a range.

Is there a way to get both the target vector and the vehicle angle in a set range where, for example, if the target angle is 0-360 and the van angle is 0-360, i can then compare them accurately?

Any other way to do this...? Any help appreciated!

Comment: okay, fixed the continous angle problem by getting the angle of the vehicle by calculating the angle of direction vector. Still stuck on the range problem though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) instead of `atan` in your code. It gets the angle from one object to another.

Comment: Thanks Secator! I used your advice and recreated my code. I'll answer my own question to post the entire snippet of code for other people who might get stuck with this.

Comment: Done. Any ideas for the steering problem, right now i'm just inputting 90 degrees is there a smarter way for this??

Comment: Sometimes 90 degrees of steering input is too much if the difference between the vehicle angle and target angle is not large. It makes the vehicle wobble between target to target.

Answer (score 0):

Using the atan2f function instead I managed to get the vehicle vector angle and target vector angle.

my new implementation is as follows:

```
 //get the direction the vehicle is facing and the direction the target is facing


CGPoint vehicleDirectionVector = ccpNormalize(ccpSub(ccp(vehicleBonnetTip.x*PTM_RATIO, vehicleBonnetTip.y*PTM_RATIO), ccp(vehicleCenter.x*PTM_RATIO, vehicleCenter.y*PTM_RATIO)));

CGPoint targetDirectionVector = ccpNormalize(ccpSub(ccp(origTarget.x, origTarget.y), ccp(vehicleCenter.x*PTM_RATIO, vehicleCenter.y*PTM_RATIO)));


vehicleAngle = atan2f(vehicleDirectionVector.x,vehicleDirectionVector.y);
targetAngle = atan2f(targetDirectionVector.x,targetDirectionVector.y);

if ( targetAngle < -M_PI / 2 && vehicleAngle > M_PI / 2 ) targetAngle += M_PI * 2;
if ( targetAngle > M_PI / 2 && vehicleAngle < -M_PI / 2 ) targetAngle -= M_PI * 2;

if ( vehicleAngle < -M_PI / 2 && targetAngle > M_PI / 2 ) vehicleAngle += M_PI * 2;
if ( vehicleAngle > M_PI / 2 && targetAngle < -M_PI / 2 ) vehicleAngle -= M_PI * 2;

CCLOG(@"vehicle angle is %f, target angle is %f", vehicleAngle, targetAngle);
```

Then to set my steering, crudely (i'm still working on this one..) i do:

```
if(vehicleAngle < targetAngle)
        {
            steeringDegrees = 90.0;    
        }
        else if(vehicleAngle > targetAngle)
        {
            steeringDegrees = -90.0;     
        }
        else
        {
            steeringDegrees = 0.0;     
        }
```